# How read date from easy tables Azure website

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I try data from my service Azure. I use next script for read.

```
module.exports = {
    function (request, response, next) {
        var query = {
            sql: 'SELECT ID, Name, Description FROM myTable ORDER BY ID'
        };
        request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
        .then(function (results) {
            response.json(results);
        });
    }
};
```

This script not show data.

Comment: It's hard to give an answer without more context. Is the query actually invoked? Do you see "response.json(results)" being called?

Comment: Yes, query in valid. Data available in table. This request good work in my MSSQL Server.

Comment: If you add a console.log('Hello world') right before response.json(results), do you see it being called? I'm trying to understand if the problem is in the flow

Comment: I added console.log('Hello world') right before response.json(results). This not show.

Comment: So the problem is in the control flow, not the database. Your query is never executed and you need to post more code with the context: e.g., what is calling your function

Comment: I just learning. This code i use successfully to easy API. How to properly retrieve data from tables? Perhaps you can use a different code.

Comment: I need to see more code (the entire context) to help you.

Comment: Any update yet?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume that you want to read data from Easy Tables on Azure Mobile App via Easy APIs. If I misunderstood, please let me know. Following is my steps to retrieve data through Easy APIs, hope this helps.

1. Create Easy API in the Azure Portal (the name I filled `myTable`), then click Edit script.
   [image]
2. Copy the following code to `myTable.js`.

   ```
   module.exports = {
      "get": function (req, res, next) {
         var query = {
           sql: 'SELECT ID, Name, Description FROM myTable ORDER BY ID'
         };
         req.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
         .then(function (results) {
             res.json(results);
         });
     }
   }
   ```
3. Request your easy API via brower.
   [image]